Categorical characterization of morphisms of rings of finite presentation
Let $f:A\to B$ be a morphism of commutative rings, and denote by $\mathcal{C}_A$ and $\mathcal{C}_B$ their categories of modules.
Is there any property of $f^*:\mathcal{C}_A\to \mathcal{C}_B$ which implies that f is a morphism of finite presentation? Said in another way, what do we have to ask $f^*$ to verify in order to ensure it comes from a morphism of finite presentation?

I can post an answer which uses the structure of $f^*$ as a tensor functor. Or do you really want to regard it as a plain functor?

Any idea is welcome.

I am not sure if this is useful for you, but there is a quite abstract characterization if we also use the symmetric monoidal structure on the functor $f^*$.
The tensor functors of the form $f^*$ are precisely the cocontinuous tensor functors (i.e. symmetric monoidal functors preserving colimits). More precisely, the category of cocontinuous tensor functors $\mathbf{Mod}(A) \to \mathbf{Mod}(B)$ is equivalent to the discrete category of homomorphisms $A \to B$. This can actually be generalized to quasi-compact quasi-separated schemes as well. See the paper Tensor functors between categories of quasi-coherent sheaves.
Moreover, we can classify morphisms locally of finite presentation categorically, see EGA IV, 8.14.2. Since you only asked for the affine case: a homomorphism $A \to B$ is finitely presented iff for every filtered diagram of homomorphisms $(A \to R_i)$ the canonical map
$$\mathrm{colim}_i \hom_A(B,R_i) \to \hom_A(B,\mathrm{colim}_i R_i)$$
is an isomorphism (bijective). This means that $B$ is a finitely presentable object in $\mathbf{CAlg}_A$.
Now we may mimic this definition for tensor functors. A cocontinuous tensor functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ may be called finitely presented (with respect to affine schemes) if for all filtered diagrams of cocontinuous tensor functors $(\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Mod}(R_i))$ the canonical functor
$$\mathrm{colim}_i \mathrm{Hom}_{c\otimes / \mathcal{C}}(\mathcal{D},\mathbf{Mod}(R_i)) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{c\otimes/\mathcal{C}}(\mathcal{D},\mathbf{Mod}(\mathrm{colim}_i R_i))$$
is an equivalence of categories. Here, $\mathrm{Hom}_{c\otimes}$ denotes the category of cocontinuous tensor functors, and the $/\mathcal{C}$ means that we are working under $\mathcal{C}$.
Then, a homomorphism of commutative rings $f : A \to B$ is finitely presented iff the associated cocontinuous tensor functor $f^* : \mathbf{Mod}(A) \to \mathbf{Mod}(B)$ is finitely presented (with respect to affine schemes). And a corresponding statement holds for all morphisms of quasi-compact quasi-separated schemes.
For more examples of this method, see Tensor categorical foundations of algebraic geometry.

You don't know it, but every time I need an answer for my thesis work, you pop up in this website. Thank yow so much!!
